# Mathematical formula to generate a curved Chinese-style roof

Tags: geometry, surfaces

I want to create a Chinese-style curved roof programmatically, something like in the right part of this picture:

[image: Chinese roof]

As seen in the picture, the roof appears to have four curved segments, which intersect at the diagonals.

I would appreciate a formula as starting point where I can tweak the parameters.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at [this paper](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~teoh/research/papers/CAE09.pdf).

Comment: That's a useful paper, thanks!

Comment: You're on your own with making the surface look "tiled", though. That's a trickier proposition... :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One (rather rough) starting point is the following surface, based on the [Lamé curve](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Superellipse.html):

$$\begin{align*}x&=v|\cos\,u|^p \cos\,u\\y&=v|\sin\,u|^p \sin\,u\\z&=\frac{hv}{c^2}(v-2c)\end{align*}$$

where $p > 1$, $h,c > 0$ are adjustable parameters, $0 \leq u \leq 2\pi$, and $v$ ranges over nonnegative values.

Here's an example, with $p=2$, $c=3$, $h=2$, and $0 \leq v \leq 4$:

[image: fake Chinese roof]

Comment: An excellent starting point, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I am not sure what you are looking for exactly, but to me this roof really looks like a pyramid to which is added the bottom of a sphere:
$$z=H - \max(\lvert x\rvert,\lvert y\rvert) + R - \sqrt{R^2-x^2-y^2},$$
where $H$ is the height of the center of the roof, and $R$ is the radius of this supposed sphere, which you can definitely tweak.

[image]

In the above example, I chose $x\in\{-1,1\}$ and $y\in\{-1,1\}$, so of course $R$ should not be smaller than $\sqrt{2}$, but the limit depends on the ranges you choose for $x$ and $y$.

Comment: A very interesting approach!

Answer (score 8):

I figured I could improve on the first answer I gave; some more tweaking with the $z$-component led me to the parametric equations

$$\begin{align*}x&=v|\cos\,u|^p \cos\,u\\y&=v|\sin\,u|^p \sin\,u\\z&=\frac{hv}{c} \left(\left(\frac{v}{c}+2f-2\right)\cos^2 2u-2f\right)\end{align*}$$

where $f > 0$ is an additional adjustable parameter.

Here is the case $p=1$, $c=9/10$, $h=1/2$, $f=2/3$, and $0 \leq v \leq 3/2$:

[image: improved Chinese roof]

I derived these new equations by starting with the parametric equations of a cone, replacing the circular cross sections with Lamé curve cross sections, and tweaking the $z$-component such that the sweeping ray linearly interpolates between a line (between corners) and a parabola (on the corners).

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x &= \frac{u+v}{2}\\
y &= \frac{u-v}{2}\\
z &= -0.3 \sin { ((\frac{|u+v|}{2} + \frac{|u-v|}{2})(\frac{|u+v|}{2} 
+ \frac{|u-v|}{2}+1)  \frac{\pi}{2} })
\end{align}
\begin{align}
-1 < u < 1, -1 < v < 1
\end{align}

[image: Drawn with Gnuplot (I hope you can plot a better one)]

From Side:

[image: Side]

Edit: Perhaps, this shows better:
[image: gnuplot2]

Comment: It was sort of intended that the edges be curved instead of being straight... you might still be able to tweak that with an approach similar to Felix's.

Comment: Added side 2d plot, and a 3d plot with better resolution.

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/HQGa4.jpg) is a better view of a Chinese roof. As I've said, note that the edges are curved. Yours are straight. You need to change your equation a bit so that the edges are curved.

Comment: Yeah, I focused on inner edges for now, not outer edges. I'm trying to do that.

Comment: That's why I said that Felix's approach might apply. Adding a spherical term or factor might be one simple way to curl your edges. (Unfortunately, I can't experiment at the moment...)

Comment: Felix's approach is 45 degrees rorated relative to my approach. And I'm still not sure which one is easier to tweak. The shaddow of Felix's approach on x-y plane is exactly an square, without using parametric plot. But I had to use u,v parameters to make it xy-square.